# Conteudo da tabela fica escondido quando contraido em telas pequenas

Tags: css, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Para um projeto da universidade estou a fazer um site simples com o objetivo de trabalhar o CSS e logicamente tem de ser responsivo.

O meu problema neste momento é que tenho uma tabela (cujo conteúdo das linhas é gerado por PHP) e quando a tento contrair em telas pequenas, ela expande bastante em altura mesmo para fora do container e fica escondida atrás do footer.

Código HTML:

```
<body>
<main>  
<div id="title">
      <h1><strong>Read</strong></h1>
  </div>   
  <!-- Container-->
  <div class="container h-50 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center outer-container body">
    <div class="inner-container"> <!-- listagem -->
      <table class="table table-striped .table-responsive-sm">
        <thead> 
          <tr>
            <td width="80" scope="col"><strong>C&Oacute;DIGO</strong></td>
            <td width="140" scope="col"><strong>NOME</strong></td>
            <td width="200" scope="col"><strong>EMAIL</strong></td>
            <td width="80" scope="col"><strong>ALTERAR</strong></td>
            <td width="80" scope="col"><strong>ELIMINAR</strong></td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result)) { ?>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"><?PHP echo $row ["codigo"]?></th>
          <td><?PHP echo $row ["nome"]?></td>
          <td><?PHP echo $row ["email"]?></td>
          <td class="td-icon">
            <a href="update.php?codigo=<?PHP echo $row ["codigo"]?>">
              <i class="fas fa-pencil"></i>
            </a>
          </td>
          <td class="td-icon">
            <a href="delete.php?codigo=<?PHP echo $row ["codigo"]?>">
              <i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i>
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
      </table>
    </div><!-- /.listagem -->
  </div><!-- /.container -->
  <div class="clear"></div>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
.table>tbody>tr>td,
.table>tbody>tr>th,
.table>tfoot>tr>td,
.table>tfoot>tr>th,
.table>thead>tr>td,
.table>thead>tr>th {
  display: block;
  min-width: 100%!important;
}
.table>thead>tr>th {
  display: none;
}

.table .filterBody span {
  display:block;
}


}
.outer-container table{
position: absolute;
margin-top: -5rem;
margin-left: -3rem;
max-height: fit-content;
}
  .clear { clear: both; height: 90px; }

 footer {
  position: fixed;
  height: 80px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.body {
  padding:10px;
  padding-bottom:90px;   /* Height of the footer */
}

.inner-container{
  position: absolute;
  width: max(30%);
}

.outer-container{
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 90px;
}
```

Eu usei as media para fazer a tabela contrair, já tentei adicionar margens no container, margens na tabela em si, até adicionei uma div "clean" para tentar criar um espaçamento, mas sempre sem sucesso.

Alguma ideia do que posso fazer?

Answer (score -2):

Podes adicionar esta propriedade ao outer-container para não haver sobreposição.

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```